# Comparison of n'th harmonic with $n\left(1+n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}-n$

Tags: inequality

In a question, I have to compare between H(n) = $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$ and $f(n) = n\left(1+n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}-n$ and state which of them is greater for n > 2(Use of calculator is not allowed).

The second function is too complicated for checking multiple values so I checked for n = 3 and found that: H(3) > f(3)

So I assumed for now that H(n) > f(n) and tried to prove it. Now to do so, since no analytic function exists for H(n), the best I could do is to find a lower bound for H(n) which will be greater than f(n).

For this, several ideas(based on past experience with such inequalities) come to mind such as:

1. AM-GM Inequality: $H(n) >= x\left(x!\right)^{-\frac{1}{x}} $
2. Using H(n) ≈ ln(n) + γ (≈ 0.5772156649, the Euler–Mascheroni constant.) For large n.
3. Induction, but I am very bad at it

But both 1 and 2 fall short. In fact, they don't even work for n = 3.

[Looking at the graph (out of frustration, can't do it in an exam ofc), It seems as if f(n) is too tight a bound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1hFh.png)

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rnw22u1sde

What do I do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}>n\left(1+n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}-n\iff \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1+i}{i}}n>\left(1+n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

and by AM-GM

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1+i}{i}}n > \left(\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1+i}{i}\right)^\frac1n=(1+n)^\frac1n$$

Comment: Thanks!! This is a great solution!!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$f(n)+n = n\left(1+n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
$$\log[f(n)+n]=\log(n)+\frac 1n \log(1+n)=\log (n)+\frac{\log
   (n)}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$f(n)+n=e^{\log[f(n)+n] }=n+\log (n)+\frac{\log ^2(n)+2}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
$$f(n)=\log(n)+\frac{\log ^2(n)+2}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Now, use the asymptotics of $H_n$ and analyze the difference $(H_n-f(n))$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I only wonder how I would think this up in an exam and even more on why my teacher thought it would be a good idea to ask this question at high school level....

Comment: @Ayaan. Just use the  first term and the difeerence is $\gamma$